# MongoDB - finding 3 averages at the same time

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I managed to write a set of code to find the average weight of customers with high budgets.

How should I modify my code so that I get the average weight of customers with high/medium/low budgets?

```
db.db1.aggregate([
    {$match:{
            "budget":"high"
    }},
    {
            $group:{
                "_id":"budget",
                "AvgWeight":{$avg:"$weight"}
            }
        }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just small change in your query.

```
db.db1.aggregate([{
  $group: {
    "_id": '$budget',
    "AvgWeight": {
      $avg: "$weight"
    }
  }
}])
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know it's that simple!